# How to fix image is not showing in heroku deployed django app

Tags: python, django

I have a Blog created with Django 3.x. When I run the project on my local server then it works fine. So, I deployed my project to heroku and here is the link [bblog-shovon.herokuapp.com/](http://bblog-shovon.herokuapp.com/). Then the project was working fine. My project git link [https://git.heroku.com/bblog-shovon.git](https://github.com/shahriar-programmer/BBlog.git)Then I created a post and then I gave it a thumbnail and finally everything was fine. But, After sometime when i revisit the site then every image were gone. I didn't found them. And when I tried to open the image on another tab then it shows this [Error message screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijUvK.png). When I am writing this question then I created a new post and after publishing this this posts image is working. But, older image is not working.

Then, How can i fix this problem? Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

Heroku flushes the filesystem to the latest commit. So you will have to use third-party plugins such as AWSBucket, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With Heroku the filesystem is not persisted so you will lose media files occasionally. Use S3 or some other provider to store your user-uploaded media (also your static files if you want, otherwise use [whitenoise](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets)). [Django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) makes it very easy.